# what is the appropriate way for writing JunitTestCases for this method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

The below code is my Method logic .

```
pulic String getData()
{ 
if (leg.length == 4)
      return "ATE";
  else  if (leg.length == 2) {
      return "FTE";
      }
    if (leg.length == 3) {
      if (xr1.KotilaType.equals("CST")) {
        return "HTE";
      }
      return "DTE";
    }
   return "BTE";
  }
```

As ordered  to me, i need to start writing Junit Test Cases for this Method.

As you can see there is only One method and a number of conditions inside this method .

Now my question is , 
Do we need to write a Seperate Junit TestCase ( A Seperate Method) for each condition ??

Or will it be sufficient to write only One Junit TestCase and cover all the above conditions ??

I am new to junit and not a expert , please guide me what is the approiate way for writing JunitTestCases for the above method ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is question of style. These are the two alternatives: With all in one method:

```
public void testAll() {
    assertEquals("ATE", getData(leg4));
    assertEquals("FTE", getData(leg2));
    // etc.
}
```

With one test method / combination:

```
public void testLength4() {
    assertEquals("ATE", getData(leg4));
}

public void testLength2() {
    assertEquals("FTE", getData(leg2));
}
```

The former has the advantage that it is very easy to see all combinations, because they're all in one place. This is very useful if there are a lot of combinations or the combinations are complex.

The latter has the advantage that you have one test per combination, so it's very easy to localize a problem, because (theoretically) only one test will fail. Disadvantage: you very quickly run out of names for test methods. testLength4, testLength2, testLength3WithCST, testLength3WithoutCST. This disadvantage gets particularly bad when you have a lot of combinations (say like one test for each month in a year).

Most of the time, I use one test method / test case, but if the number of combinations starts to get high, I would have a single method. This contains all of the combinations, because I like to be able to see all of my combinations at once, to see if I've missed any.

Comment: Actually, I would say that the single test case is *bad* style. no offense =)  The reason is that if your first assert fails, then you have no idea if the other asserts would pass or fail. So, you might see a failure, go fix some code, rerun the test, and find... the test still fails! Just on a different assert. This also makes it harder to use metrics to decide how unstable a build is, etc. Basically, you are trading ease of writing tests (which are usually written once so we might as well take the time to do it right) with information we gain from those tests.

Comment: @Kane I agree, but if I have 20 or so combinations, and I'm changing the code, and all of the combinations are in separate tests, then it is very hard to work out if I've covered all of the cases. So under normal circumstances, I have one test / case, but I don't mind multiple combinations in the same method.

Comment: Fair enough, I can understand why how would come into play. But if you're concerned that you haven't covered all the cases, shouldn't your code coverage tool tell you that? I would be lost without mine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with five unit tests for each possible return value, setting the object under test's state (leg.length & xr1.KotilaType) to appropriate values in each test.

Then i'd move to tests that covered boundary values e.g. leg.length == 5, 1 etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew Farwell and Bedwyr Humphreys